# jQuery: How to remove appended item on click toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm appending a class on click of a 'span'. I'm able to remove that appended div on  click on other icon and append there. How can I add toggle on every icon clicked twice .This is my jquery below:

```
  var toggle = true;
$('.extra-items span').on('click',function() {
    $(".mid-side .same-category").remove();
    if(toggle)
    {
        $(this).closest(".row").append($(".media-categories-all").html());
        toggle = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).closest(".mid-side .same-category").remove();
        toggle = true;
    }
})
```

There are a lot  of 'span' also. When it's appended on first click on a icon.. it removes that also in the first click of another icon and nothing is appended in that first click.

Thank you brso05

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global variable and use it to toggle:

```
var toggle = true;
$('.extra-items span').on('click',function() {
    //removed remove() here
    if(toggle)
    {
        $(this).closest(".row").append($(".media-categories-all").html());
        toggle = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).closest(".mid-side .same-category").remove();
        toggle = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: There are a lot lot of 'span' also. When it's appended on first click on a icon.. it removes that also in the first click of another icon and nothing is appended in that first click.

Comment: You have a `remove()` right above your `if` statement. I will update my answer see if it works...

Comment: @ShuvoHabib Part of the problem is you are using classes to do your on click and only one toggle variable. You would need each span to have its on toggle tracker.